# How to build a publisher to pass a string

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Does anybody know how to pass string between different nodes?
msgs seems to only contain limited number of types, which a string is not included.
So when I do

```
transport::PublisherPtr statePub = node->Advertise<msgs::string>("~/sentence");
```

,it doesn't work.

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4603/how-to-build-a-publisher-to-pass-a-string/) by [EdwardC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/484/edwardc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

there is a gzstring i guess this is suppossed to be used for pure String messages...

here is a
[list of message types provided by Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/msgs/1.9.0/classes.html)

Here's a [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/custom_messages) about using cutom messages...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1